# Django admin inline - remove "object referenced" (blank)

Tags: django, object, admin

I have extended the user model with this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='Tell us about you...')
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default=' ')
```

And appended the admin.py:

```
    class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User Profile'
    verbose_name = 'Additional Info'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product)
```

In the admin panel where verbose_name is being displayed, it is showing `Additional Info: UserProfile object` - not sure where `UserProfile object` is coming from.  I've attached a screenshot below:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that, other using CSS to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#str) method of your model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='Tell us about you...')
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default=' ')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Note that this will render the `username` you could also do:

```
self.first_name
```

or

```
self.last_name
```

**EDIT**

Since you wan it to be blank the only way is to return a space like so,

```
return ' ' #must add a space
```

The reason is that `__str__` must return a string type object. so returning something like `None` or `''` would cause an error.

Comment: Thanks - that appended the username to the verbose_name - is there a way to make it blank?

Comment: Got it ...phew!  Appreciate the help!  Does there need to be a value there?

Comment: Played around and used this - hopefully I'm not breaking any rules:  `def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name`

Comment: No problem! Accept the edit so your title becomes relevant to your question.